# xtable::xtableList modify latex align for message (multicolumn)

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I am using xtableList to generate a table in latex with groupings. I am *very* close, but I would like to line-wrap the "message" section at the end and I can't find the right incantation to make it work. Using an example from the gallery (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/listOfTablesGallery.pdf):

```
library(xtable)
data(mtcars)
mtcars <- mtcars[, 1:6]
mtcarsList <- split(mtcars, f = mtcars$cyl)
### Reduce the size of the list 
mtcarsList[[1]] <- mtcarsList[[1]][1,]
mtcarsList[[2]] <- mtcarsList[[2]][1:2,]
mtcarsList[[3]] <- mtcarsList[[3]][1:3,]
attr(mtcarsList, "subheadings") <- paste0("Number of cylinders = ",names(mtcarsList))
attr(mtcarsList, "message") <- c("Line 1 of Message","Line 2 of Message")
str(mtcarsList)

xList <- xtableList(mtcarsList)
print.xtableList(xList,
                 tabular.environment = "tabularx", 
                 width = "0.8\\textwidth",
                 floating=FALSE)
```

My only modification from the example is I've defined it in the 'tabularx' environment (reason below). Output is

```
> print.xtableList(xList,
+                  tabular.environment = "tabularx", 
+                  width = "0.8\\textwidth",
+                  floating=FALSE)
% latex table generated in R 3.3.3 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Wed Jul 01 17:23:59 2020
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt \\ 
  \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 4}\\
Datsun 710 & 22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 & 3.85 & 2.32 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 6}\\
Mazda RX4 & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.62 \\ 
  Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.88 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 8}\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 175.00 & 3.15 & 3.44 \\ 
  Duster 360 & 14.30 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 245.00 & 3.21 & 3.57 \\ 
  Merc 450SE & 16.40 & 8.00 & 275.80 & 180.00 & 3.07 & 4.07 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Line 1 of Message}\\

\multicolumn{7}{l}{Line 2 of Message}\\
\end{tabularx}
>
```

The problem is that my text replacing `Line 1 of Message` is very long and needs to wrap. It doesn't do that here. Manual editing of the .tex file led me to find that modifying the multicolumn line to `\multicolumn{7}{X}{Line 1 of Message}\\` is *exactly* what I want!

Is there any way to modify the R code so that the end result looks like this? Or even with align defined as "X" for every multicolumn line would be fine.

```
% latex table generated in R 3.3.3 by xtable 1.8-4 package
% Wed Jul 01 17:23:59 2020
\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{rrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & mpg & cyl & disp & hp & drat & wt \\ 
  \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 4}\\
Datsun 710 & 22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 & 3.85 & 2.32 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 6}\\
Mazda RX4 & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.62 \\ 
  Mazda RX4 Wag & 21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 & 3.90 & 2.88 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{l}{Number of cylinders = 8}\\
Hornet Sportabout & 18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 175.00 & 3.15 & 3.44 \\ 
  Duster 360 & 14.30 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 245.00 & 3.21 & 3.57 \\ 
  Merc 450SE & 16.40 & 8.00 & 275.80 & 180.00 & 3.07 & 4.07 \\ 
   \hline
\multicolumn{7}{X}{Line 1 of Message}\\

\multicolumn{7}{X}{Line 2 of Message}\\
\end{tabularx}
>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.